# How to get selected checkbox row's value using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to get the values of selected check box row's value using Jquery.

For that, First I try to alert a message,if user checked the checkbox using Jquery. But I failed.

> **Note:** I am adding checkbox in a row using Jquery, and then User will select the checkbox.

**Here is my code to add checkbox in row through AJAX code**

```
$('#btnSearchVendor').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "GPCreateCheque.aspx/BindData",
        data:"{}",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success = "+data.d[0].DOCTYPE);
            for(var i=0;i<data.d.length;i++){
                $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1").append("<tr><td><input id=\"Checkbox"+i+"\" class=\"checkBoxClass\" type=\"checkbox\" /></td><td>" + data.d[i].DOCTYPE + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].DOCNUMBR + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].ActualAmount + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },
        error:function(result){
            alert("Error");
        }
    })
})
```

**Jquery code to make alert when user select the checkbox**

```
$('.checkBoxClass').click(function () {
    alert("Checkbox state (method 1) = " + $('.checkBoxClass').prop('checked'));
    //alert("Checkbox state (method 2) = " + $('.checkBoxClass').is(':checked'));
});
```

**Above code is working fine, I added the checkbox. Below pic is the output with console**
[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: use event delegation if you add the checkbox dynamically use `.on()`

Comment: @guradio can you please give me a example with code?. thanks

Comment: elevating on @guradio's comment I would suggest to use `$("body").on("click", "#idOfElement", function(){ //code here });` if you are dynamically creating the checkboxes

Comment: Put a working code with snippet

Comment: Read up on ***[Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)***

Comment: And you want the current element...not the first checkbox with that classss which is what `$('.checkBoxClass').prop('checked'));` returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following script for this

```
$(document).on('click','.checkBoxClass',function () {
    alert("Checkbox state (method 1) = " +  $(this).prop('checked'));

    if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        alert("Actual Amount = " + $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last-child').html());
    }
});
```

Comment: This will only show checked property of ***first*** `.checkBoxClass` in the page... has nothing to do with the one that event occured on

Comment: @SuperUser error occurred like `".checkBoxClass".is is not a function`

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: @SuperSuper thanks, It's working. Can you tell how can I get that column's name of `Actual Amount` of selected row

Comment: @mohamedfaiz check updated answer

Comment: @SuperUser please don't choose last child. Can you choose by column number. because In actual record I will have more than 8 column, So **How can I choose particular column?**

Comment: @mohamedfaiz it depands on you which column you want. you can use `:nth-child(4)` for this. or you can add a class to it and set a custom selector

Comment: @SuperUser thanks, I got it. I add the id for that td, then I use that id to get the value.

Comment: instead of `id` you can use `class` because `id` should have unique value on page, & as per your question you have repeated `tr`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get the corresponding row value of the clicked checkbox

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.checkBoxClass').on('click', function() {
    debugger
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      var columns = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(:first-child)');
      $(columns).each(function(index) {
        console.log("Column " + (index + 1) + " has value " + $(this).text());
      });
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
      <th>Head 3</th>
      <th>Head 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' class='checkBoxClass' /></td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' class='checkBoxClass' /></td>
      <td>Content 222</td>
      <td>Content 3333</td>
      <td>Content 4444</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It makes sure that value is printed on console only when checkbox is selected.